# SQL injections in Sharepoint Enterprise SQL search syntax

Tags: security, sharepoint, full-text-search, sql-injection

I am designing a web part where users can enter a search phrase the MOSS Search index is sought for that. I use `FullTextSqlQuery` class for searching.

When I create my `select` statement, I apparently have to use concatenation to include the user's input in it. The final statment should be something like this:

```
 SELECT title, author from portal..scope() 
 WHERE ("SCOPE" = 'TheDocuments') 
 AND CONTAINS(MYPROPERTY, 'TheValueThatuserSpecified')
```

So, the question is, how do I avoid SQL(?) injections from user input? Is there some specific utility function for that? In php/mysql projects I'd use `mysql_real_escape_string`. Anything similar in SharePoint namespaces?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't found any function to encode user input so I created my own method:

```
protected override string EncodeUrlParameter(string paramValue)
{
   StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
   for (int i = 0; i < paramValue.Length; i++)
   {
       char c = paramValue[i];
       if (c == '*' || c == '%' || c == '[' || c == ']' || c == '_')
           sb.Append("[").Append(c).Append("]");
       else if (c == '\'')
           sb.Append("''");
       else
           sb.Append(c);
   }
   return sb.ToString();
}
```

This is mainly used for parameters filtered using the LIKE keyword ([the documentation page has a note about this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms452722%28v=office.12%29.aspx)). The biggest thing I stumbled upon was when people tried to include apostrophes in their queries.

Answer (score 2):

> The FullTextSQLQuery class takes a
>   "full text sql" query which is not
>   true sql. The "full text sql" is
>   parsed and converted to regular sql to
>   query against table in the sql server
>   database and to query against an
>   external index file. There is no way
>   to do sql injection via "full text
>   sql", it will not pass validation. The
>   "column names" you use in the "full
>   text sql" must be valid "managed
>   properties" that are set up in Search
>   Administration, they do not point to
>   actual column names on a table.

http://www.sharepointdev.net/sharepoint--search/is-fulltextsqlquery-protected-against-sql-injection-35184.shtml

Comment: True, but this way the user could anyway enter search phrase like `') AND CONTAINS (ANOTHERPROPERTY, 'Anothervalue) OR (SCOPE='AnotherScope`. This renders a valid search query, but in quite a different way. Another point is - you have to take care of escaping apostrophes, quotes etc.

Comment: CONTAINS predicate will only work against managed properties that have been enabled as FullTextQueriable. Also, Retrievable flag. This flag prevents a Managed Property’s value from being returned if specified as a column in the SELECT statement.

Comment: Also, search results are security trimmed, so even if you manage to get your injected query to run you will only get results that you normally have access to anyway.